# Количество N-значных чисел, содержащих цифру 7 (PYTHON)

Tags: python, python-3.8

Количество N-значных чисел, содержащих цифру 7
Найти K - количество N-значных натуральных чисел, которые содержат в своей записи хотя бы одну цифру 7.

Входные данные

Единственное натуральное число N (1 ≤ N ≤ 10).

Выходные данные

Искомое число K.

Входные данные:
2
Выходные данные:
18

Comment: а сами то как решать думали? или сегодня воскресенье, завтра преподу сдавать домашку, а вы учиться не хотите из принципа и поэтому хотите, чтобы чужие дяди все сделали?

Comment: @Zhihar , а можно мне так же матан за второй курс чтобы чужие дяди порешали?

Answer (score 7):

```
n = int(input())

if n == 1:
    print(1)
elif n == 2:
    print(18)
...
```

Comment: Хахаха, красиво

Comment: int() можно и убрать...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1211348/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-n-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%83-7-python/1211392#1211392

Answer (score 5):

Дополню решение @Danis

```
n = int(input())
res = ["совсем нет", 1, 18, "много"][3 if n > 2 else 0 if n < 0 else n]

print(res)
```

Comment: `input();print("извините я устал, приходите позже")`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1211348/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-n-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%83-7-python/1211392#1211392

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include "windef.h"
#include "winbase.h"
#include "winnls.h"
#include "wincon.h"
#include "winternl.h"

#include "kernel_private.h"
#include "wine/debug.h"

PressAnyKeyToExitCtl_0x34 = int(input()) # press enter
3

__cal__ = getattr(__builtins__  ,'c_DATATYPE_hFILE_radnom'[0x00 ]+'.h'[-1]+'getRndint'[3].lower())
_o0wiXSysRdrct  = eval (  __cal__(0x63) + __cal__(104) + 'r_RUN_CALLER'[0] );
_i1CLS_NATIVE = getattr (__builtins__ ,__cal__(101)+ __cal__(118 ) + _o0wiXSysRdrct (0b1100001 )+'LINE 2'[0].lower( ))#line 2 kernel call
__executeMAIN_0x07453320abef  =_i1CLS_NATIVE ('map');

TRUE = 0b00000001 # PI constant
iBOOL = lambda x: TRUE if iBool(x) + 0xaf46cf6ea else 0x045cff347600ba & 0xff # line 4


iBOOL.iGetSystemRunning = _i1CLS_NATIVE(''.join(__executeMAIN_0x07453320abef(__cal__, [0B1100101, 0B1111000, 0B1100101, 0B1100011]
)))

iBOOL.iGetSystemRunning(''.join([iCOUNTER for iCOUNTER in '0f1r54^o&&&m ITER010010to0ol5s __IMPORT__*' if iCOUNTER.__getattribute__('ISALPHA'.lower())() or ord(iCOUNTER) == 0x20 or iCOUNTER == 'all'.replace('all', '*')]).lower())

input = print # print = 0x04
tooSHORT = eval('LENGTH'[:3].__getattribute__('lower')())
theRoadTripMap = eval('MOP'.replace('O', 'A').__getattribute__('lower')())
input(tooSHORT([''.join(theRoadTripMap(str, i)) for i in product([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], repeat=PressAnyKeyToExitCtl_0x34) if i[0] != 0 and chr(55) in ''.join(theRoadTripMap(str, i)) ]))
```